# How to manage videos on Android via Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I wish to play a simple video file (.mov or mp4) on my Android device via Unity. I have Unity 5.5.2 personal, and Movie Texture is not supported on Android.

I can run my video by placing it in the StreamingAssets folder and using this code:

```
void Start()
{
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("myVid.mp4", Color.black,
                                 FullScreenMovieControlMode.Minimal,FullScreenMovieScalingMode.None);

}
```

How to control to audio of the video by code?

How to change the video alpha (making it half transparent for example)?

Comment: You can't with `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie`. Maybe you will be able to by replacing Color.black with `new Color(0f,0f,0f,0.5f)`. The `0.5f` for alpha. Not sure if this will work but you should now be using Unity's new  `VideoPlayer`. All you have to do is set the `RawImage` alpha.

Comment: Can I use VideoPlayer or VideoSource in Unity 5.5.2 free edition?

Comment: It's %100 free and must download Unity 5.6 not 5.5.2. It's a new feature.